# How do I include a third party SQL table into a asp.net code first web application?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

It would be nice to be able to access the third party table in the same ApplicationDbContext that is generated by code first. But ultimately I really want to be able to join on the table in a linq query that translates into a single sql query (dont want it to make two database calls because I am joining two database contexts)

The table is a zipcodes table purchased from a third party. It does not have a unique id as code first requires, so I would have to give it one i guess?

Comment: How is the third party table added to your database? Are you using Code FIrst Migrations?

Comment: It is a sql script that I ran in Sql Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using Code First Migrations to manage the database, you could just create a model for the zip codes table. The EF model for the table and the table itself don't necessarily have to match, so you could create a class to represent a zip code table record, and set a key for the zip codes entity even if the database table itself doesn't have one. You would have to be sure that the chosen key is unique or you would get unexpected results.

If you're using Code First Migrations, the same thing applies, but you can also run the SQL script itself in a `DbMigration` or in the `DbMigrationsConfiguration.Seed`.

Comment: If I ran it as a dB migration would it create the class for me? Could you link me to what you mean by that ? Much appreciated.

Comment: @masteroleary: the dbmigration wouldn't be for creating the class, I was thinking about the case where you would create the rest of the database using code first migrations. In that case, instead of running the SQL script in SSMS every time you need to recreate the database, you could have the script run in the seed function or during a migration. In any case, since you're doing code first, you would still need to create the class.

Comment: Ok. When adding new item I see their are several options for ado.net entity model, ef context genreator, link to sql class. I thought one of these options would be used to generate a class from the existing table so that the data types would match without me writing the glass manually. Linq to sql does that but doesn't add the class within the existing dB context created by my code first models. Guess it can't be do t that way.